# java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/F10.bin

Tags: android, file, kotlin, exception

Trying to access a binary file which in below location :

> /storage/emulated/0/Download/F10.bin

I have also verified in my device and its there.

Using Samsung M51 android device.

Trying to access it as below :

```
val fileData = Files.readAllBytes(
                Paths.get(
                    File(
                        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                            .toString() + "/" + "F10" + ".bin"
                    ).absolutePath
                )
            )
```

Also verified the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in app settings.

But, while executing above code of line getting exception as below :

```
    2021-08-10 08:17:56.922 4564-3361/? E/MediaProvider: Permission to access file: /storage/emulated/0/Download/F10.bin is denied
System.err: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/F10.bin
System.err:     at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
System.err:     at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
System.err:     at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
System.err:     at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3152)
System.err:     at com.sa.verne.appview.home.update_firmware.viewmodel.UpdateFirmwareViewModel.readDownloadedFirmwareFile(UpdateFirmwareViewModel.kt:153)
System.err:     at com.sa.verne.appview.home.update_firmware.viewmodel.UpdateFirmwareViewModel$upgradeFirmwareFromLocal$1.invokeSuspend(UpdateFirmwareViewModel.kt:133)
System.err:     at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
System.err:     at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

What might be the issue?
Please guide.

**EDIT**
Used below code to download file using download manager :

```
 /**
 * Method that downloads the file.
 * */
fun downloadFile(
    baseActivity: Context,
    batteryId: String,
    downloadFileUrl: String?
): Long {

    //Getting file extension i.e. .bin, .mp4 , .jpg, .png etc..
    val fileExtension = downloadFileUrl?.substring(downloadFileUrl.lastIndexOf("."))
    val downloadReference: Long

    //creating download manager instance...
    var objDownloadManager: DownloadManager =
        baseActivity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager

    //initializing URI from file url...
    val uri = Uri.parse(downloadFileUrl)

    //initializing Request for download a file...
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)

    //download when...
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
        DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or
                DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE
    )

    //download path...
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
        "" + batteryId + fileExtension
    )

    //set notification
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)

    //Setting Title
    request.setTitle(batteryId + fileExtension)

    //download reference
    downloadReference = objDownloadManager.enqueue(request)

    return downloadReference
}
```

Comment: did you grant the required permission?

Comment: @mightyWOZ Yes I also checked it manually in Device settings. Location and Storage permission is granted.

Comment: This will happen only on an Android 10 device?

Comment: it's on Androd 11

Comment: Can anyone suggest that How can I move the file from Downloads to app internal storage?

Comment: And your app did not put that file there! Tell how it landed there please.

Comment: You cannot even copy/read the file. Let it be deleting original. As you have no read nor write access.

Comment: @blackapps Added code for download manager which saving my file in Downloads.

Comment: DownloadManager can put files in Download directory without needing permission rights of your app. Register a download receiver. When download done you can obtain an uri from the downloadmanager. Use that uri to access your file.

Comment: We can not access it. As you see I am trying to access it in above code and getting exception.

Comment: It? No. You are not trying to access an uri obtained from DownloadManager. You put a file path together. Please reread my comment.

Comment: @blackapps I am storing the file path in my local database and when needed have to use that path, that's why I am using file path to check that it's accessible or not.

Comment: You should use the uri. And store the uri. That path is useless as you should know by now.

Comment: @blackapps I have successfully download the file using URI dear Sir and file is also saved in Download folder. That's why for later use I am using the file path which is stored in database to read that file.

Comment: I see that you let the DownloadManager use an uri for a file in Download directory. Well the DownloadManager has acces to that file. Your app has not. I said that before

Comment: But i was mistaken, having Android 10 in mind. On an Android 11 device you should be able to use that file path. Be it you requested access in the usual way. If not use the uri you can obtain from the manager. (Not the uri you gave it).

Comment: @blackapps The solution I found is to use DownloadService (Intent Service) to download the file using URL Connection instead of DownloadManager. and saved file in app internal storage as using File api : filesDir